# Display a pdf file entered as a custom field file

Tags: wordpress, pdf, advanced-custom-fields

Please i've added custom field to my portfolio posts, one of the field should be a pdf file, i'm using avada theme wordpress, and i need to create a custom layout of all my portfolio pages, i would  like to dynamicly display my pdf files and the user should be able to see them on the portfolio page.

I've tried to use Custom field dynamicly and to display the field as an array, but all that i keep having on the frontend is just the pdf url. i've tried to use the pdf custom field as an embeded field too and i've installed the embeded pdf plugin but the results are the same. Please if anyone can help thaank you

Comment: How about this? https://wordpress.com/support/embed-a-pdf-file/ It uses the Media subsystem rather than custom fields.

Comment: Yes but i need to creat a global layout for all the portfolio post so it needs to be an custom field that is the problem

Comment: I managed to find a solution, i've created the pdf custom field as a text and used the Embed Any Document plugin which generated a short code for the pdf it worked like a charme yey